# Global Header Bar on custom visualforce page

Tags: community, header-bar

Before winter 14, visualforce pages loaded within a new communities site would would automatically load the new black global header bar where users can edit their settings and switch between sites.  But now it seems that if you have a visualforce page that isnt showing the sites standard header (ie showHeader="false") its also not showing the global header

Is there anyway to show just the black header bar without the full salesforce site header anymore?

Something like this?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxleo8zs54swt9w/Screenshot%202013-10-29%2013.32.00.png

Answer (score 1):

No. With `showHeader="false"` the global header will never show.

You could create your own global header if you wanted.

The screenshot you posted is interesting. It looks like that page actually has `showHeader="true"` and there is custom CSS loaded on the community level (set in community setup) that is overriding the standard salesforce header.

Comment: Hmm that's what I was afraid of...  Hmm. Have you ever tried to recreate the global header?  The site switcher I could do fine, but what I can't seem to get working is the user settings?   The page I should is a standard page with a custom static header ( which are showing the global header) but I have some pages that are loading without any standard header at all..,  hmmm

Comment: I've never setup the user settings overlay by hand. It looks way too intricate.